# Does splicing change the target of a spell

Tags: magic-the-gathering

I cast an instant and my opponent casts a counter and I splice an additional spell to my original instant does this prevent the counter.

Comment: The title and the body ask two seemingly different questions. Does splicing change the target of a spell? If I splice onto a spell, does that prevent the spell from being countered? I would update your post to focus on one or the other.

Comment: @Rainbolt I am guessing that the user misused the phrase “target of a spell”, meaning to say “change it into a new object that will no longer be targeted by the counterspell”.

Answer (score 8):

Well, first of all, you cannot do that.

These are the rules for Splicing:

> 702.46a Splice is a static ability that functions while a card is in your hand. “Splice onto [subtype] [cost]” means “You may reveal this card from your hand as you cast a [subtype] spell. If you do, copy this card’s text box onto that spell and pay [cost] as an additional cost to cast that spell.”
>   Paying a card’s splice cost follows the rules for paying additional costs in rules 601.2b and 601.2f–h.

This means that you need to splice the spell **as you cast** whatever you're splicing onto.

Also, as @ikegami pointed out, Splicing onto a spell will not create a new object. Even if you could splice a spell onto another spell that had already been cast, the target for the counterspell wouldn't be changed.

Answer (score 2):

No to both of your questions, but you seem to misunderstand how splicing works. Splicing is part of the uninterruptible steps of casting a spell. If you intend to splice onto your spell you do it as you cast, you announce the spell, put it onto the stack, add any splices, add up the total cost and pay it, all before your opponent even gets the chance to cast a spell in response. You don't get to know your opponent is not going to counter the spell before you decide to splice, and they do get to know everything you have spliced onto it before they decide if they are going to counter.